# Unable to send request body to API endpoint in a JavaScript fetch()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, post, fetch-api

I am trying to create an asp.net core API which receives a JSON stringified object through a POST request. To send a POST request to this API I use the JavaScript `fetch()` function. In the body of the POST request, I send a stringified object to the backend, but when the backend receives the request the body value is empty! Why is this?

**My JavaScript post call:**

```js
 function BindSupervisor() { 
                        (() => {
                            const rawResponse = fetch('mu_url', {
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify({aa:'W15'})
                            });
                            const content = rawResponse.json();
                            console.log(content);
                            })();
                     }
```

**My API backend:**

```js
public JsonResult supervisors_name(string aa)
         {
           // My logic
            return Json (supervisors);
        }
```

Comment: In your backend, where are you getting the `supervisors` variable? Or do I not understand asp.net?

Comment: supervisors variable in my logic which i donot want to disclose . but problem is not that, i donot get the 'aa' value. That my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I send a stringified object to the backend, but when the backend receives the request the body value is empty*

That's because your client is sending **a json payload,** while the server is expecting **a plain string**:

```
public JsonResult supervisors_name(string aa)
```

As a result, the string `aa` is always `null`.

---

**How to fix :**

You could send the payload and bind the parameter both in `JSON` format, or you could also send and bind the payload both in `String` format. But don't mix them up.

#### Approach 1 (Json format):

create a dummy `Payload` class to hold the `aa` property:

```
public class Payload {
    public string Aa {get;set;}
}
```

And change the action method to accept a `Payload` parameter :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult supervisors_name2([FromBody]Payload data)
{
    // now you get the data.Aa
    return Json (supervisors);
}
```

Don't forget the `[FromBody]` if you're using a non-api controller.

#### Approach 2 (string format):

In case you want to receive the json body as a plain string, you need to declare a `[FromBody] string aa`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult supervisors_name([FromBody]string aa)
{
    // now you get the aa as string
    return Json (supervisors);
}
```

The client should send the request with a header of `Content-Type: application/json`.